# Inserting text into ckeditor

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I need to insert a text into ckeditor in the exact place where my cursor is positioned on a button click.
How can I do that?
I m using ckeditor in asp.net.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [insertHtml](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#insertHtml) API call.